# Is this Class Diagram Correct?

Tags: class, uml, class-design

I need some help to confirm I am on the right track with this.
I did a use case diagram and class diagram for the popular online shopping scenario.

Please look through it and criticize constructively, let me have your views on it as I am still learning UML.

The story behind the modeling is shown below:

> The name of the company is X-company and they are into the sales of
>   paints. X-company has a website that sells these paints online to two
>   types of customers - retailers and wholesalers.   X-Company has a few
>   paints currently which vary in color, size, cost each paint-type
>   obviously varying in these characteristics. Retailers can log into the
>   site and purchase paints in single digits (like 1 or 2 paints) at a
>   time while wholesalers buy paints in large quantities at discounts of
>   10% for 10 paints and above, 20% for 20 paints and above, 30% for 30
>   paints and above.
>
> The website has been made to be easy as possible. Customers get to the
>   site, selects the type of paint and is shown the characteristics of
>   the paint. If the customer accesspts to purchase they select the
>   quanitity they need. If the customer is ok with the price they then
>   confirm their order. on confirmation, the website checks for the stock
>   of paints to see if there are enough paints available. If there are
>   not available, the customer is notified and asked to select another
>   type. If they are available, the customer provides payment card
>   details such as address, card number, card pin. The payment is done
>   through an external integration. On payment, the customers order is
>   sent to the customer except if the customer requests a cancellation or
>   the order through the website administrator.
>
> The website-organizer or administrator is responsible for adding new
>   paints to the website and taking out old paints when there is a new
>   stock of paints.

The class diagram I have drawn is shown below:

[image: Class Diagram]

Comment: This looks too much like a homework assignment. Do you have specific UML questions?

Comment: Im Assuming class `User` is abstract, would be good to label it so.

Answer (score 2):

- Give the classes singular names. Order, not Orders. Discount, not Discounts. If you have a class that is a collection\list of Orders, however, then "Orders" would be fine.
- A User cannot buy more than one kind of paint at a time! The Order class should have a collection of Paint, not a single Paint instance.
- Paint, PaintType design does not seem logical. I don't see why there should be more than one class. Combine into a Paint class.
- I think there should be a PaintStock class. The methods in the Administrator class seem to be things that are done to PaintStock, so move them over. The Administrator class needs a PaintStock reference so it can call PaintStock.Add, etc.
- Payment class should be called CreditCardPayment given what's in it. I suspect that credit card is not the only way make payments. I'd make a Payment base class so we can easily expand the ways to pay later on.
- Add/Remove paint functions are inappropriate for the Administrator class. Put these methods in a PaintStock class.
- Rename BulkBuyer to Wholesaler
- Consider one User class. Get rid of Retailer and Wholesaler. I don't see a difference worth different classes. Make a BuyerType field in the User class to differentiate. If your business rules dictate purchase limits based on retailer vs wholesaler, that simple rule difference can easily live in one class.
- As a general rule - and it's a good one - do not store calculation results. So Order.TotalCost should be a method not a field.
- Order needs a Cancel method. NOT the Administrator class. The Administrator class needs an Order reference so it can call Order.Cancel.